# Removal of special characters from string using perl script

Tags: regex, perl, scripting, perlscript

I have a string like below

```
stringinput = Sweééééôden@
```

I want to get output like

```
stringoutput = Sweden
```

the spl characters  `ééééô`  and `@` has to be removed.

Am using

```
$stringoutput = `echo $stringinput | sed 's/[^a-z  A-Z 0-9]//g'`;
```

I am getting result like  `Sweééééôden`  but `ééééô` is not getting removed.

Can you please suggest what I have to add

Comment: You need `stringoutput=$(echo $stringinput | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]//g');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LC_ALL=C` before `sed` command to make `[A-Za-z]` character class create ranges as per ASCII table:

```sh
stringoutput=$(echo $stringinput | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]//g')
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Wgd70N):

```sh
stringinput='Sweééééôden@';
stringoutput=$(echo $stringinput | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]//g');
echo "$stringoutput";
# => Sweden
```

See [POSIX regex reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> In the default C locale, the sorting sequence is the native character order; for example, ‘[a-d]’ is equivalent to ‘[abcd]’. In other locales, the sorting sequence is not specified, and ‘[a-d]’ might be equivalent to ‘[abcd]’ or to ‘[aBbCcDd]’, or it might fail to match any character, or the set of characters that it matches might even be erratic. To obtain the traditional interpretation of bracket expressions, you can use the ‘C’ locale by setting the LC_ALL environment variable to the value ‘C’.

In Perl, you could simply use

```perl
my $stringinput = 'Sweééééôden@';
my $stringoutput = $stringinput =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]+//gr;
print $stringoutput;
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/A1b3Po).

Comment: Thanks a lot .

my $stringoutput = $stringinput =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]+//gr;

this worked.

But when I added / to regex .. since I dont want / occurance from stringinput  like 
PO BOX 29794/MACééééô S3929-033

It throwed an error below
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[ <-- HERE ^A-Za-z0-9 / at splchar.pl line 11.

I have used below regex
$stringout = $stringin =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9 /-.,]+//gr;

Comment: @sravanisrinija You used `-` inside the brackets, right? Escape it (or place at the end of the bracket expression). Also, escape `/`. `my $stringoutput = $stringinput =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9 .,\/-]+//gr;`

Comment: Note: Both assume an NFC string and fail for NFD strings (producing Sweeeeeoden instead of Sweden). See [Unicode Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

Answer (score 4):

No need to call sed from Perl, perl can do the substitution itself. It's also faster, as you don't need to start a new process.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

my $string = 'Sweééééôden@';
$string =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]//g;
print $string;
```

Comment: My bad. This comment will self-destruct.